# How do I choose an <option> twice on a <select> element (API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, select, reset

I have a dogAPI and was wondering if there was a way to select the same breed twice without having to select another option and then delete the output (say the user only wants output of a single breed).  I am thinking I have to reset the select menu so it will automatically go to the first option but the code I tried doesn't work on elements that were added to the DOM from an API.  Here is what I have tried and here is my codepen.

https://codepen.io/drxl/pen/VwbQZyK

```
function createClassOption1() {
    let option = $('<option>Choose a dog breed</option>');
    option.addClass('default');
}

const resetSelect = $('#breeds').find('option');
$('#breeds').change(e => {
    const value = $('#breeds').val();
    console.log(value);
    $('#breeds').val(defaultOption.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<select>` element is dynamically created via the `breedList` function... So you will need to use a delegated event listener.

Then, if you want to "reset" the selection, you can use the `selectedIndex` property. I would suggest you to do it inside a setTimeout, so the user see the select resetting approximately when the image has loaded.

```
$("#breeds").on("change", "select", function() {
  const value = this.value;
  console.log(value);
  let select = this
  setTimeout(function(){
    select.selectedIndex = 0;
  },800)
});
```

[Codepen fixed](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oNWEJeQ?editors=0011)